# Why Declaring a TextView object with the same name twice create an error while Declaring it inside a loop doesn't?

Tags: java, android

For me the loop is repeating some instructions over and over again so if my code is like this :

```
int i = 0;
while(i<3){
System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
```

it means for me that i wrote the same instruction 3 times like this :

```
System.out.println("Hello world!");
System.out.println("Hello world!");
System.out.println("Hello world!");
```

i'm a wrong ?

so if my code is like this:

```
int i = 0 ;
while(i < 3){

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
}
```

it means for me that i wrote the instruction 3 times like this :

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

isn't it ? 
so whey when i write this code :

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

it gives me an error because i have repeated the same name ( textView ) two times but writing the same thing whithin a loop like this do not give me an error

```
    int i = 0 ;
while(i < 2){

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
}
```

even if it is the same thing .
is there any problem in my way of understanding things ( loops ) or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the loop ends, your old `TextView` is being destroyed and a new one is being created. This is no problem, because as soon as the loop ends it's gone forever.

If you just stack three declarations on top of each other, they are NOT being destroyed, instead those three would all remain in memory, and it is illegal to have two variables with the same name (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 0):

It is about variable scope. You can't declare the same name variable in the same scope.

```
while(i < 2){
// this variable's scope is this loop. Outside this loop it is not recognized
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
}
```

What your code equals is this:

```
while(i < 2){
  new TextView(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell Output of this loop ?

Comment: It will create three Textviews. But you wont be able to reference to them with the 'textview' variable because your reference's scope was the inside of the loop. Outside of the loop the variable is not recognized.

Comment: did you mean this loop generate only one `textview` finally ? final variable overrides on previous`textviews` ?

Comment: a variable is a reference to the real object. On the first iteration of the loop you create a TextView and your textView variable references to it. But when loop body ends your textView variable got destroyed because its scope ended. But the object still exists.On the second iteration you create another TextView and your textView variable references to it. But at the end of the loop body again your textView variable got destroyed but the TextView object still exists. Now you have two TextViews but you don't have a variable that references to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not android specific question but general JAVA concept

If you define

```
int a=3;
int a=3;
int a=3;
```

It will throw error
But
If you create a loop

```
while(i<3)
    {
        int a=3;
    }
```

It wont throw error

Everytime the loop ends, it destroys previous objects and thus on each iteration its the new one that is initialized